# Bash regular expression: zero to three numbers

Tags: regex, bash, ls

I have this files

```
file00.txt
file01.txt
...
file99.txt
file102.txt
file102.txt
```

and

```
file00.extra.txt
file01.extra.txt
...
```

in bash (ls) with regular expression, how I can show files without `.extra` ?

I try with

```
 ls file[0-9]\{1,3\}.txt
```

but don't show nothing.

Comment: The headline doesn't match the Text. Do you search 0-3 numbers, or do you want to exclude "extra"? Do you want to remove 'extra' from the name, or hide the file from listing? Is this homework: ls-lesson?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [bash extended pattern matching](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching):

```
shopt -s extglob
ls file+([0-9]).txt
```

To find between 1 and 3 numbers

```
ls file[0-9]?([0-9])?([0-9]).txt
```

Comment: I thought about extglob as I was typing out my answer. You beat me to it.

Comment: Is there a way to use the `hide` option of `ls`?  I can't get an example to work.  Perhaps because I don't know how to specify "pattern".  Anyone?

Comment: disble extglob with `shopt -u extglob`

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing with ls is a glob, not a regular expression. To find files based on a regex, you will need to use find.

```
find ./ -regex '.*/file[[:digit:]]\{1,3\}\.txt'
```

This will recurse into all subdirectories. To prevent this, you can use -maxdepth.

```
find ./ -maxdepth 1 -regex '.*/file[[:digit:]]\{1,3\}\.txt'
```

Answer (score 1):

Grep to the rescue:

```
ls file*.txt |grep -v extra
```

Comment: I think in similar solution, maybe use `sed`, but I need use only regular expresion

Comment: JuanPablo - why do you *need* to use regex? Is the problem different than what is stated, or homework?

Answer (score 1):

After rereading the question 3 times, and the comment to the answer of Frank Schmitt, who used grep (the tool of evil), I have the impression it is homework/ls-lesson.

Then I have a completely different answer:

```
ls --hide="*.extra*"
```

My first impression was, that we shall remove 'extra' from the filename, with this solution:

```
for f in file* ; do echo $f; done 
file00.extra.txt
file00.txt
file01.extra.txt
file01.txt
file102.txt
file99.txt
```

Display without .extra.:

```
for f in file* ; do echo ${f/.extra./.}; done 
file00.txt
file00.txt
file01.txt
file01.txt
file102.txt
file99.txt
```

The string substitution `${f/.extra./.}` replaces `.extra.` with `.` (dot).

Comment: That doesn't find files that don't have ".extra", that just removes it from the filename.

Comment: I'm not sure whom of us understood Juan right. I thought he wanted to display the filenames, even if they contain 'extra', but without 'extra'. But maybe you're right. Your interpretation makes maybe more sense.

Comment: I am pretty sure that is what was meant, but I agree "how I can show files without .extra" can be a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1):

If your files are all relevant in that directory (i.e. no extraneous files), you can use a built-in option of `ls`:

```
ls -l --hide="*extra*"
```